# Change response required for Rails authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, devise

I've a user model and a login route. Using ember-simple-auth, whenever I'm sending the data for authentication, the data is required to be  in this format:

`{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"admin@admin.com"}`

However, I want the data to be in this format:

`{"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"admin@admin.com"}}`

How can I change this?
Thanks.
Code: https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-server

Comment: is not clear enough.  {"email"=>"nirmalya.email@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"} is working fine and user successfully authenticated. You just neeed to reformat your params hash? But it's unclear why do you actually need this?

Comment: I need this because I'm sending the data like this from the Frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a possible approach you can override `resoure_params` method

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController

  private

  def resource_params
    params.permit(user: params_for_resource(:sign_in))[:user]
  end
end
```

routes

```
namespace "api" do
  namespace "v1" do
    mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
      sessions:  'api/v1/sessions'
    }
    resources :users
  end
end
```

Then if your params looks like

```
{ 
    "user": {
        "email": "nirmalya.email@gmail.com",
        "password":"password"
    }
}
```

you will receive success response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "provider": "email",
        "uid": "nirmalya.email@gmail.com",
        "name": "Nirmalya Ghosh",
        "nickname": null,
        "image": null,
        "email": "nirmalya.email@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

But I'm **strongly** recommend to refactor your frontend to meet `devise_token_auth` reqirements and pass params as `{email: "foo@mail.com", password: "password"}`